# Manually drilldown highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple level drilldowns.

Given series id I would like to drilldown to the corresponding using a function like

```
function drilldown(id) {
   // function drills down to the series having id
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fire an event manually like this:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].hcEvents.click[0]();
```

Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mqnyy9cu/

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue!
Also, how to fire a click event with control key enabled?

Comment: Do you mean: ctrl key pressed?

Comment: Yes. I figured that we can do this -
`ev = new MouseEvent('click',{ctrlKey: true})
chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click', ev);`

Please let me know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Your solution seems pretty elegant - if it works there's no need for searching another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this?

Yes

This is the sample code

```
chartConfig.chart.events.drilldown = function(e) {

                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    var chart = this,

                        drilldowns = drillDownColumChartData,

                        drilldowns2 = drillDownLinChartData,

                        columnSeries = drilldowns[e.point.drilldown],

                        lineSeries = drilldowns2[e.point.drilldown];

    

                    setTimeout(function() {

                        /*https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2989*/

                        if (e.point.x != null) {

                            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, columnSeries);

                            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, lineSeries);

                            chart.yAxis[1].setTitle({

                                text: secondaryYaxisTitle

                            })

                            chart.applyDrilldown();

                        }

                    }, 0);

                }

            };
```

You can get the selected point details from `e.point`

Refer [Highcharts asyc drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/)

Comment: What I am trying to do is this.

I load the chart with multiple levels of drilldown.
When an event is triggered, I update the main series data and drilldown data. But I want to preserve the drilldown state and load new data in the same drilldown state!

Comment: Means you want to achieve multiple drilldown... Right?

Comment: Yes! But I want to do it manually outside the event handlers of the chart!

When I click a button, it updates the series and drilldown data. But I want to display the chart with updated data in the drilldown where it currently is in!